# org-at-timestamp-p is not correctly detecting when at a timestamp

Tags: emacs, org-mode

`org-at-timestamp-p` is supposed to test if point is at a timestamp.

I've written the following function to test it:

```lisp
  (defun my/test-timestamp ()
    (interactive)
    (if (org-at-timestamp-p)
        (message "Point is at timestamp")
      (message "Point is not at timestamp")))
```

When I run this on a timestamp (either active or inactive), it does not detect a timestamp.

If I instead test for `(org-at-timestamp-p 'inactive)`, it does correctly test for inactive timestamps.

Is there something I have overlooked?

I am running:
Org Version: 9.5.5
Emacs Version: GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.36, cairo version 1.17.6)